# Unable to find a specification for `React-Core`

Tags: react-native

trying to install "react-native-camera" to my project.
I'm following those steps: https://github.com/react-native-camera/react-native-camera/blob/master/docs/installation.md#requirements

But at "Additional installation steps" when I use "pod install" It returns;

```
[!] Unable to find a specification for `React-Core` depended upon by `react-native-camera/BarcodeDetectorMLKit`

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
```

My Podfile below:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'


target 'blabla' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'react-native-camera', path: '../node_modules/react-native-camera', subspecs: [
    'BarcodeDetectorMLKit'
  ]
  # Pods for blabla

  target 'blablaTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

target 'blabla-tvOS' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for blabla-tvOS

  target 'blabla-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

React native version is 62.0.
React-native-camera version is 3.40.0

What could be problem?

Answer (score 0):

add manually to your Podfile the pod missing:

`pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'`